Ecuador, Peru public transport apps and websites
Is there some app to search for public transport (coaches, buses, trains) in Ecuador and Peru?
If not, are there at least list of websites with coaches and trains (I know trains are somehow limited at least in Ecuador)?
I found only for coaches
https://www.ecuabuses.com/eng
and for city bus
https://moovitapp.com/index/en/public_transit-Ecuador
I'm not sure if they are the best ones.

If we are talking about public transit, Google Maps have OK coverage of Lima buses.

I'd start with Rome2Rio.

Late response, but are you looking for intercity specifically, or transportation within cities? Within cities Google Maps may have limited coverage, and Moovit should have coverage based on operator (though its reliability is dependent on its data sources being kept up to date). Larger cities may have better options.

For longer trips https://www.ecuabuses.com/eng worked quite well, but there were some non-existing services (hm), prices were outdated. Also smartphone apps did not work for us (required local ID number). I have to say in the end it was easiest to ask locally in the bus terminal (the same applies for Peru as well). But what I was surprised that employees of concurrent companies just shout laud what is going to go instead having electronic board usual in Europe.
